# Value error :Cannot convert string to float

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc=OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
X=[['gender', 1], ['NationalITy', 2], ['PlaceofBirth', 3],['StageID', 4], ['GradeID', 5], ['SectionID', 6],['Topic', 7], ['Semester', 8], ['Relation', 9],['raisedhands', 1], ['VisITedResources', 2], ['AnnouncementsView', 3],['Discussion', 4], ['ParentAnsweringSurvey', 5], ['ParentschoolSatisfaction', 6],['Class',7]]
enc.fit_transform(X)
```

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 enc.fit_transform(X)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in
>   fit_transform(self, X, y)    2017         """    2018         return
>   _transform_selected(X, self._fit_transform,
>   -> 2019                                    self.categorical_features, copy=True)    2020     2021     def _transform(self, X):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in
>   _transform_selected(X, transform, selected, copy)    1807     X : array or sparse matrix, shape=(n_samples, n_features_new)    1808
>   """
>   -> 1809     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csc', copy=copy, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)    1810     1811     if isinstance(selected,
>   six.string_types) and selected == "all":
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in
>   check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy,
>   force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
>   ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
>       431                                       force_all_finite)
>       432     else:
>   --> 433         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
>       434 
>       435         if ensure_2d:
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'gender'

Comment: It works for me using `scikit-learn-0.20.3` and `scipy-1.2.1`

Answer (score 1):

From this post,

[OneHotEncoder Error: cannot convert string to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404130/onehotencoder-error-cannot-convert-string-to-float)

you can see that it does not work but with integers. However, now, the documentation says that it works with integers.

Maybe you should update your version, because it should be able to convert strings.

For me the piece of code from the edit has worked perfectly.